# How to do a Validation in php for my Registration form?

Tags: php, validation

Am Newbie here.Am Beginner in php.I Create a sample Reg form.Here i want to Validate My all Fields is Not equal to Empty like that. i have text field,check box,Radio button,Select box & Email field.
Please tell with Example.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use this http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html . And by the way LEARN to write before posting. Your question is almost undecipherable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errors = array();
$required = array("Name", "Email");  
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        $$key = $value;
    }
    else
    {
         if(in_array($key, $required))
         {
             array_push($errors, $key);
         }
    }        

}
```

This should work for checking empty values. Just add the keys of the required fields in your form to the required array. The $$key = $value creates a variable with the same name as the key and puts the value in their for you. So if your fields were "Name" and "Email" after the loop you could access the variables $Name and $Email with the correct values in.

You may want to check and display the errors afterwards like so

```
if(empty($errors))
{
    //send email
}
else
{
    //display errors
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
        echo "<li>" . $error . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an [example](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html) of php form validation.

Another [example](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/server-side-form-field-validation-with-php-only) for [form](http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/check_empty_form_fields.php) empty field validation.

Example:

```
<?PHP
require_once "formvalidator.php";
$show_form=true;
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $validator = new FormValidator();
    $validator->addValidation("Name","req","Please fill in Name");
    $validator->addValidation("Email","email",
"The input for Email should be a valid email value");
    $validator->addValidation("Email","req","Please fill in Email");
    if($validator->ValidateForm())
    {
        echo "<h2>Validation Success!</h2>";
        $show_form=false;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<B>Validation Errors:</B>";

        $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
        foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
        {
          echo "<p>$inpname : $inp_err</p>\n";
        }
    }
}

if(true == $show_form)
{
?>
<form name='test' method='POST' action='' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
Name: <input type='text' name='Name' size='20'>
Email: <input type='text' name='Email' size='20'>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
<?PHP
}//true == $show_form
?>
```